# cakephp 3 paginate sort custom field

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

i try to sort "hasMany" associate

this is my code :

Advisor Modal

```
    $this->hasMany('AdvisorNotes', [
        'foreignKey' => 'id',
        'sort' => [
            'created' => 'DESC',
        ],
        'joinType' => 'LEFT',
    ]);
```

Advisor Controller

```
public function index() {
    $this->paginate = [
        'contain'       => [
            'Branch'       => [ 'BranchCity', 'Bank' ],
            'AdvisorLevel',
            'AdvisorRelation',
            'UsersAgent',
            'AdvisorNotes'
        ],
        'sortWhitelist' => [
            'BranchCity.city_name',
            'Branch.name',
            'Advisor.name',
            'AdvisorRelation.relation',
            'AdvisorLevel.level',
            'Advisor.telephone',
            'UsersAgent.name',
            'AdvisorNotes.created',
            'Bank.name',
        ]
    ];
    $advisors       = $this->paginate( $this->Advisor );
```

AdvisorNotes table 
id | advisor_id | agent_id | type_id | note | created

Advisor table
id | name | image | date_of_birth | important_date | branch_id | telephone | fax | cellphone | email | description | level_id | relation_id | agent_id | agent_admin_id | created

i try to make field in the Advisor index that show the last AdvisorNote and be able to sort it.

as you can see AdvisorNotes as advisor_id in table but Advisor dont have any id of the AdvisorNotes.

thanks.

Comment: If you want to show the last one (in time) just use your field "AdvisoNotes.created" (already in you sortWhitelist), in this case, you don't need for a custom field

Comment: but this is "hasMany" and it wont add it to the all result and i got : 

Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'AdvisorNotes.created' in 'order clause'